# How to return MutableSet from linkedSetOf with list data?

Tags: android, kotlin, type-mismatch

"I'm preparing to create a MutableSet,how can i return it from a LinkedHashSet?"

"There is List data,then i tried to create a MutableSet from a LinkedHashSet with the list data."

In Java,i create a Set like this:

```java
private Set<Item> mItems;
public void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
        if (bundle == null) {
            mItems = new LinkedHashSet<>();
        } else {
            List<Item> saved = bundle.getParcelableArrayList(STATE_SELECTION);
            mItems = new LinkedHashSet<>(saved);
        }
    }
```

In kotlin,i wrote code like this:

```
var mItems: MutableSet<Item>? = null
fun onCreate(bundle: Bundle?) {
        if (bundle == null) {
            mItems = linkedSetOf()
        } else {
            val saved = bundle.getParcelableArrayList<Item>(STATE_SELECTION)
            mItems = linkedSetOf(saved)
        }
    }
```

But there is a type mismatch alert from AndroidStudio compiler:Required:Item,Found:ArrayList!

or do i need to do like this?:

```
mItems = linkedSetOf(saved) as MutableSet<Item>
```

And i use covert java to kotlin ,it generates code like this:

```
mItems = LinkedHashSet(saved)
```

But the LinkedHashSet is from java.util.LinkedHashSet,is there some way in kotlin more idiomatic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write `linkedSetOf(*saved.toTypedArray())`. Not sure if it more idiomatic :) It's ok to use some things from Java in Kotlin. Underneath, `linkedSetOf` uses `LinkedHashSet` as well.

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin always creates a `LinkedHashSet` when you ask for a `MutableSet` so you can just use the standard methods.

```
private lateinit var mItems: MutableSet<Item>

public override fun onCreate(bundle: Bundle?) {
    mItems = bundle?.getParcelableArrayList(STATE_SELECTION)
                   ?.toMutableSet() ?: mutableSetOf()
}
```